# Ajax enabled sorting and paging on grid in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sorting, webforms, paging

Is there any good solution for ajax enabled Grid with pageing and sorting which only brings the required data from database? I mean it should only bring the data from the database which is to be displayed on the particular page number of the grid.

I looked at [this](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/aspnetajaxgridandpager.aspx). It looks good. But I just thought if anyone has created something better using Google's or Yahoo's javascript library or using any good features of asp.net 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm replying my own question.

I found [Ajax Data Controls](http://ajaxdatacontrols.codeplex.com/) as updated version of what I had specified in my question. Still I will not mark it as answer and will wait for better answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a datasource control (SqlDataSource, LinqDataSource etc) this would be done automatically (retrieving only the current page of data). To make paging and sorting ajax-enabled wrap the grid inside an UpdatePanel control.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now I'm giving finishing touches to the GridView created using Ajax Data Controls. Will see that next time. But still Ajax Data Control grid view looks better to me.

Answer (score 0):

I used [devexpress grid](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GroupingSorting/Sorting.aspx). It has sorting, grouping and paging. It is not perfect one but looks nice and easy to use.

Comment: It's nice and is there any word for more easier than easy. Then I would say it's that. Literally there is nothing to code in it. But the biggest draw back is that it's not free. Otherwise I would have used it. :(
Thanks any way :)

Comment: Try jQuery grid: http://www.trirand.net/demo.aspx
I don't know about licensing though